# raise ValueError('invalid destination language')

Tags: python-3.x, valueerror

[image]

I'm getting an error like in the picture, because I'm a newbie, I don't know how to fix it, please help me, thank you very much

```
from googletrans import Translator
#print(googletrans.LANGUAGES)
t = Translator()
a = t.translate("em dep qua", src = "vi", dest = "em")
print(a)
```

I wrote the above code guess, after printing the screen, I get this error " ValueError: invalid destination language "

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying `en` instead:

```
a = t.translate("em dep qua", scr="vi", dest="en")
```

Comment: I edited it as you instructed, but it gave me an error like this 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @MinhTríTrần I solved your current problem, so please accept my answer and ask another question...